# Forcing a Set Resolution in wx.Python in Full Screen

Tags: python, wxpython

I am making a program in wx.Python that is set to be in full screen, but I have an unresolved question about screen resolution.

I know how to detect the size of a window, and set the positions of items proportionally.  And my program is currently doing this.

But is it possible to force the full screen to display at a fixed resolution of my choosing regardless of display resolution?  (If it was, I could make one wide screen and one full screen layout to cover everyone.)

I have searched for a solution to this, but cannot find a lead!  Perhaps it is simply impossible in wx.Python.  But if not, can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this?  So many devices are using lcd displays which look horrible when they're not running in their hard-wired resolution.

Comment: Oh.  That's interesting.  Well, if that's the case, then maybe I don't want to do it at all and will keep with my detecting resolution and spacing things proportionally plan.

Comment: oh! you actually are a Dilligent Student !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're proposing is impossible. If the resolution of the monitor is set to 1900x1600 and you set your app to run at 800x600, the app will NOT be fullscreen. You can't be fullscreen and be less than the resolution of the monitor. And I would argue that you can't have your application be larger than the maximum resolution of the monitor if you want your app to be usable.

Can you set the Frame's size? Of course you can. You do that when you instantiate the frame. Can you make it fullscreen? Yup. The frame object has a method called ShowFullScreen() just for that purpose. You can also screw around with style flags to modify it a little too. See also http://wiki.wxpython.org/Using%20Frame.ShowFullScreen

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can force a specific video mode/resolution. Depending on your display/drivers the result (on an LCD screen) may be scaled up to fill the display or shown in a sub-rectangle of the screen (e.g. letterbox). However, that may not actually be what you want unless you need a specific output resolution -- for video capture or output to a specific device, for example. The wxPython code to do this would be something like:

```
display = wx.Display(0)  # if you have multiple monitors, use its index
desired_mode = wx.VideoMode(width, height, color_depth)
supported_modes = display.GetModels(desired_mode)
if len(supported_modes) > 0:
    display.ChangeMode(supported_modes[0]) # just use the first match for now
```